# Method to check connectivity to other server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I want to check connectivity between 2 servers (i.e. if ssh will succeed).

The main idea is to check the shortest way between server-a and server-b using a list of middle servers (for example if I'm on dev server and I want to connect to prod server - usually a direct ssh will fail).

Because this can take a while, I prefer not to use SSH - rather I prefer to check first if I can connect and if so then try to connect through SSH.

Some possible routes to get the idea:

```
server-a -> server-b
server-a -> middle-server-1 -> server-b
server-a -> middle-server-6 -> server-b
server-a -> middle-server-3 -> middle-server-2 -> server-b
```

Hope you understand what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For checking server connectivity you have 4 tools at your disposal.

1. ping

   This will check to see if any of the servers you're attempting to connect through, but won't be able to see if middle-server-1 can reach server-b, for example.

   You can gate how long ping will attempt to ping another server through the use of the count switch (`-c`). Limiting it to 1 should suffice.

   ```
   $ ping -c 1 skinner
   PING skinner (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from skinner (192.168.1.3): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=5.94 ms

   --- skinner ping statistics ---
   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.946/5.946/5.946/0.000 ms
   ```

   You can check the status of this command through the use of this variable, `$?`. If it has the value 0 then it was successful, anything else and a problem occurred.

   ```
   $ echo $?
   0
   ```
2. traceroute

   Another command you can use to check connectivity is `traceroute`.

   ```
   $ traceroute skinner
   traceroute to skinner (192.168.1.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
   1  skinner (192.168.1.3)  0.867 ms  0.859 ms  0.929 ms
   ```

   Again this tool will not show connectivity through one server to another (same issue as ping), but it will show you the path through the network that your taking to get to another server.
3. ssh

   `ssh` can be used in `BatchMode` to test connectivity. With `BatchMode=yes` you'll attempt to connect to another server, bypassing the use of username/passwords and only public/private keys. This typically speeds things up quite a bit.

   ```
   $ ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" skinner
   ```

   You can construct a rough one liner that will check for connectivity to a server:

   ```
   $ ssh -q -o "BatchMode=yes" skinner "echo 2>&1" && echo $host SSH_OK || echo $host SSH_NOK

   SSH_OK
   ```

   If it works you'll get a `SSH_OK` message, if it fails you'll get a `SSH_NOK` message.

   An alternative to this method is to also include the `ConnectTimeout` option. This will guard the `ssh` client from taking a long time. Something like this typically is acceptable, `ConnectTimeout=5`. For example:

   ```
   $ ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 skinner echo ok 2>&1
   ok
   ```

   If it fails it will look something like this:

   ```
   $ ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 mungr echo ok 2>&1
   ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.2 port 22: No route to host
   ```

   It will also set the return status:

   ```
   $ echo $?
   255
   ```
4. telnet

   You can use this test to see if an `ssh` server is accessible on another server using just a basic `telnet`:

   ```
   $ echo quit | telnet skinner 22 2>/dev/null | grep Connected
   Connected to skinner.
   ```

Comment: I use your third suggestion(without the bacth-mode) and sometimes I need to stay connected(if it succeeded of course) and still get the SSH_OK/SSH_NOK message. What do I need to correct in the command?

Comment: Method four is nice. To avoid the grep and use the exit code only, use the escape character: `echo ^]quit | telnet skinner 22`

To enter `^]` in Bash, press Ctrl-V, Ctrl-].

Answer (score 10):

`nc` can "ping" port as well

```
nc -z hostname 22
```

this way you can ping port 22 on machine even if the machine is configured not to respond to regular ping (ICMP)

Comment: -z is not supported in centos  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1243773

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try cutting down the SSH time by setting some config options, like `ConnectTimeout=1`. `UseDNS=no` also helps with systems that don't have reverse DNS configured correctly.